# Add two arrays with nested components into a new 'combined' array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to combine two arrays with nested components into a new array. Best explained with example:

```
InputValues1 = [
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -1},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2},
            {"Input1": 2, "Input2": -2},
            {"Input1": 4, "Input2": -4}
        ],
        "Name": "AA",
        "key": 1
    },
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2},
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 5},
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}
        ],
        "Name": "AB",
        "key": 2
    }
]
InputValues2 = [
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 1},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 1},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 6}
        ],
        "Name": "BA",
        "key": 1
    },
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 30, "Input2": 1},
            {"Input1": 6, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 8}
        ],
        "Name": "BB",
        "key": 2
    }
]
```

The new combined output needs to be:

```
CombinedOutput = [
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 4, "Input2": 1},
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": -1},
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": -1},
            {"Input1": 5, "Input2": 2}
        ],
        "Name": "AABA",
        "key": 11
    },
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 31, "Input2": -1},
            {"Input1": 9, "Input2": 7},
            {"Input1": 4, "Input2": 4},
            {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 6}
        ],
        "Name": "ABBB",
        "key": 22
    }
]
```

So I'm looking to sum the nested *Values* arrays together, and concatenate the *Name* and *key* values.

I'm thinking the map function might be useful here, but I'm a little lost as to how to deal with the nested aspect as well as not create a mess with for loops.

I've shown the InputValues as having 2 entries each, but this could be larger, so I'm worried about my crude thinking of for loops.

Comment: This has nothing to do with react. Tag removed.

Comment: What makes them pairs? Only the position? Or the `key`? Or will they always match? If they don't match, `22` is also in `InputValues1`, `InputValues2` order (like what happened to `"Name": "AABA"`)? Are the outer arrays of equal size for sure? And the inner ones? `map()` is not necessarily a good pick in any case, but it's especially not if `key` matters or the array lengths can differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest keeping your head and breaking the problem down into small manageable chunks. Don't be afraid to use lots of functions.

```js
const InputValues1 = [{"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 4, "Input2": -4}], "Name": "AA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 5}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}], "Name": "AB", "key": 2}]

const InputValues2 =  [{"Values": [{"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 6}], "Name": "BA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 30, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 6, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 8}], "Name": "BB", "key": 2}]

const expectedOutput = [{"Values": [{"Input1": 4, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": -1}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": -1}, {"Input1": 5, "Input2": 2}], "Name": "AABA", "key": 11}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 31, "Input2": -1}, {"Input1": 9, "Input2": 7}, {"Input1": 4, "Input2": 4}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 6}], "Name": "ABBB", "key": 22}]

const output = combineInputValues(InputValues1, InputValues2)

if (JSON.stringify(output) === JSON.stringify(expectedOutput))
    console.log("Boy, we did it!")
else
    console.log("Back to the drawing board, son", output)

function combineInputValues(inputValuesOne, inputValuesTwo) {
    if (inputValuesOne.length !== inputValuesTwo.length) throw new Error("Input arrays not of same length")
    const combinedArray = []
    for (let i=0; i < inputValuesOne.length; i++)
        combinedArray[i] = combineSingleInputValue(inputValuesOne[i], inputValuesTwo[i])
    return combinedArray
}

function combineSingleInputValue(inputValueOne, inputValueTwo) {
    return {
        Values: combineValues(inputValueOne.Values, inputValueTwo.Values),
        Name: inputValueOne.Name + inputValueTwo.Name,
        key: Number(inputValueOne.key.toString() + inputValueTwo.key.toString()),
    }
}

function combineValues(valuesOne, valuesTwo) {
    if (valuesOne.length !== valuesTwo.length) throw new Error("Input arrays not of same length")
        const combinedArray = []
    for (let i=0; i < valuesOne.length; i++)
        combinedArray[i] = combineSingleValuesEntry(valuesOne[i], valuesTwo[i])
    return combinedArray
}

function combineSingleValuesEntry(entryOne, entryTwo) {
    return {
        Input1: entryOne.Input1 + entryTwo.Input1,
        Input2: entryOne.Input2 + entryTwo.Input2,
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst I found all responses hugely helpful, given my 'beginner' status in JavaScript I found this answer helped me the most in understanding how to break down my problem into manageable and understandable chunks.

Also, I very much appreciate the encouraging words (keeping my head and not being afraid to use many functions!). Has made me even more determined to continue my learning.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Below, I'm using `.map()` in a function I've created called `merge` to map each object to a transformed object. Each transformed object is built by using [`Objeect.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate and access the current object's keys/values. The transformed object has the same keys from the current object, but the values are transformed. If the current value is an array, I recursively call `merge()` to perform the same logic on the nested arrays and transform the inner objects. If it's not an array, then we merge the values together based on your rules - If the key is either `Name` or `key`, you concatenate, otherwise we add. I've defined these rules in an object, that's used by a callback function you can pass to `merge` and then called with the two values we're trying to combine together:

```js
const InputValues1 = [{"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 4, "Input2": -4}], "Name": "AA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 5}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}], "Name": "AB", "key": 2}];
const InputValues2 =  [{"Values": [{"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 6}], "Name": "BA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 30, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 6, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 8}], "Name": "BB", "key": 2}];

const merge = (arr1, arr2, op) => {
  return arr1.map((obj, i) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => [
      key, 
      Array.isArray(val) 
        ? merge(val, arr2[i][key], op)
        : op(val, arr2[i][key], key)
    ])
  ));
}

// Define the rules for combining
const ops = {
  key: (a, b) => +`${a}${b}`, // string concatenation but we convert the value back to a number (using the unary plus `+`) 
  default: (a, b) => a + b // string concatenation or numeric addition, depending on a and b types
};
const combine = (a, b, key) => ops[key]?.(a, b) ?? ops.default(a, b); // try and call the ops[key] if that key exists in `ops`, otherwisee call `ops.default` function to merge `a` and `b` 
const combined = merge(InputValues1, InputValues2, combine);
console.log(combined);
```

Comment: seems overengineered, too complex and many intermediate arrays. 22.50x slower than simple `forEach()` iteration (check my answer)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Yes, if I was aiming for speed I wouldn't write it like this, it's a more of a declarative and dynamic approach which ends up consuming more recourses/time (this question was also originally tagged as React, so my assumption was that these arrays shouldn't be mutated directly). On a second read of the question, and looking at the other answers, the recursive part may not be needed as well, but it'll handle dynamic array values if needed so I decided to leave it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function to iterate over the arrays and combine them.

```js
// Define the input arrays
let InputValues1 = [
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -1},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2},
            {"Input1": 2, "Input2": -2},
            {"Input1": 4, "Input2": -4}
        ],
        "Name": "AA",
        "key": 1
    },
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2},
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 5},
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}
        ],
        "Name": "AB",
        "key": 2
    }
];

let InputValues2 = [
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 1},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 1},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 6}
        ],
        "Name": "BA",
        "key": 1
    },
    {
        "Values": [
            {"Input1": 30, "Input2": 1},
            {"Input1": 6, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 2},
            {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 8}
        ],
        "Name": "BB",
        "key": 2
    }
];

// Define the function
function combineArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.map((item1, index) => {
        let item2 = arr2[index];
        return {
            Values: item1.Values.map((value, i) => {
                return {
                    Input1: value.Input1 + item2.Values[i].Input1,
                    Input2: value.Input2 + item2.Values[i].Input2
                };
            }),
            Name: item1.Name + item2.Name,
            key: parseInt(item1.key.toString() + item2.key.toString())
        };
    });
}

// Call the function
let CombinedOutput = combineArrays(InputValues1, InputValues2);

// Log the result
console.log(CombinedOutput);
```

Using a `Map` to iterate over two input arrays in parallel. For each pair of elements,  a new `object` is created with the concatenated value, name, and key. Values ​​are combined by iterating through the "values" array in parallel and creating a new object for each pair of values.
The Map function is used to iterate over the "Values" array in parallel, and the "+" operator adds values. The `parseInt` function is used to convert concatenated keys to integers. I assume that the two input arrays are the same length and that each object's "value" array is the same length. If not, you may need to add an error-checking code.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the functions for merging.

```js
const
    a = [{ Values: [{ Input1: 1, Input2: -1 }, { Input1: 1, Input2: -2 }, { Input1: 2, Input2: -2 }, { Input1: 4, Input2: -4 }], Name: "AA", key: 1 }, { Values: [{ Input1: 1, Input2: -2 }, { Input1: 3, Input2: 5 }, { Input1: 3, Input2: 2 }, { Input1: 1, Input2: -2 }], Name: "AB", key: 2 }],
    b = [{ Values: [{ Input1: 3, Input2: 2 }, { Input1: 2, Input2: 1 }, { Input1: 1, Input2: 1 }, { Input1: 1, Input2: 6 }], Name: "BA", key: 1 }, { Values: [{ Input1: 30, Input2: 1 }, { Input1: 6, Input2: 2 }, { Input1: 1, Input2: 2 }, { Input1: 1, Input2: 8 }], Name: "BB", key: 2 }],
    addByKey = (a, b) => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(a)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v + b[k]])
    ),
    outerObject = (a, b) => ({
        Values: map(addByKey)(a.Values, b.Values),
        Name: a.Name + b.Name,
        key: '' + a.key + a.key
    }),
    map = fn => (a, b) => a.map((v, i) => fn(v, b[i])),
    merge = map(outerObject);
    
console.log(merge(a, b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can solve that with this small generic function

```
function zipWith(a, b, fn) {
    let res = Array.isArray(a) ? [] : {}
    for (let k of Object.keys(a)) {
        res[k] = fn(a[k], b[k], k)
    }
    return res
}
```

It accepts two arrays or objects and creates a new array/object by applying a callback function to the "left" and "right" items pairwise.

The callback in your case would be a function that either adds arguments if they are scalars or recursively zips them otherwise:

```
function adder(a, b, key) {
    if (typeof a === 'object')
        return zipWith(a, b, adder)
    return a + b
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
 CombinedOutput = zipWith(InputValues1, InputValues2, adder)
```

It's not clear from your post what you're doing with the `key` key, so this is left as an exercise (hint: in the `adder` function, add a branch `if (key === 'key') { ... }` to handle it in a special way).

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate items in the second array, find corresponding items from the first one (create a copy of it) and add values.

The trick here that the key should be combined too, but we need to find the items from the first array, so combine keys under `_key` property and then replace it to `key` in the end.

As you see this make the code very fast more than 15x faster than the other solutions.

```js
const result = InputValues1.slice();
InputValues2.forEach(e => {
  const found = result.find(e2 => e.key === e2.key);
  if(found){
    e.Values.forEach((v, idx, arr, v2 = found.Values[idx]) => (v2.Input1 += v.Input1, v2.Input2 += v.Input2));
    found.Name += e.Name;
    found._key ??= found.key;
    found._key += '' + e.key;
  } else result.push(e);
});
result.forEach(e => (e.key = +e._key, delete e._key));
// ready, display result
result.forEach(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)));
```

```html
<script>
const InputValues1 = [{"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 4, "Input2": -4}], "Name": "AA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 5}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}], "Name": "AB", "key": 2}]
const InputValues2 =  [{"Values": [{"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 6}], "Name": "BA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 30, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 6, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 8}], "Name": "BB", "key": 2}]
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/120
--------------------------------------------------------
Alexander    1.00x  |  x1000000  128  129  132  135  140
Nina        15.86x  |   x100000  203  204  205  206  209
Nick        22.50x  |   x100000  288  293  294  297  299
--------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const InputValues1 = [{"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 4, "Input2": -4}], "Name": "AA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 5}, {"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": -2}], "Name": "AB", "key": 2}]
const InputValues2 =  [{"Values": [{"Input1": 3, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 2, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 6}], "Name": "BA", "key": 1}, {"Values": [{"Input1": 30, "Input2": 1}, {"Input1": 6, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 2}, {"Input1": 1, "Input2": 8}], "Name": "BB", "key": 2}]

// @benchmark Nick
const merge = (arr1, arr2, op) => {
  return arr1.map((obj, i) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => [
      key, 
      Array.isArray(val) 
        ? merge(val, arr2[i][key], op)
        : op(val, arr2[i][key], key)
    ])
  ));
}

// Define the rules for combining
const ops = {
  key: (a, b) => + ('' + a + b), // string concatenation but we convert the value back to a number (using the unary plus `+`) 
  default: (a, b) => a + b // string concatenation or numeric addition, depending on a and b types
};
const combine = (a, b, key) => ops[key]?.(a, b) ?? ops.default(a, b); // try and call the ops[key] if that key exists in `ops`, otherwisee call `ops.default` function to merge `a` and `b` 
merge(InputValues1, InputValues2, combine);

// @benchmark Nina
{

const addByKey = (a, b) => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(a)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v + b[k]])
    ),
    outerObject = (a, b) => ({
        Values: map(addByKey)(a.Values, b.Values),
        Name: a.Name + b.Name,
        key: '' + a.key + a.key
    }),
    map = fn => (a, b) => {
        const result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) result.push(fn(a[i], b[i]));
        return result;
    },
    merge = map(outerObject);
merge(InputValues1, [...InputValues2]);
}
// @benchmark Alexander

const result = InputValues1.slice();
InputValues2.forEach(e => {
  const found = result.find(e2 => e.key === e2.key);
  if(found){
    e.Values.forEach((v, idx, arr, v2 = found.Values[idx]) => (v2.Input1 += v.Input1, v2.Input2 += v.Input2));
    found.Name += e.Name;
    found._key ??= found.key;
    found._key += '' + e.key;
  } else result.push(e);
});
result.forEach(e => (e.key = +e._key, delete e._key));
result;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: yes the others are slower because of the dynamic style vs hard coded properties.

Comment: Whilst I won't pretend I followed this fully,  it looks like this relies upon the keys being identical, which whilst true in my example inputs,  is not the case.

I still found this useful to aid my understanding of different approaches. Thanks